# Using Ag Grid have the columns respect the content and render at 100% width of parent container

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Using Ag Grid:

1. Have the columns respect the minimal content width required to display as does `autoSizeColumns()`
2. Render **at least** the **full width** of the parent container similar to `setColumnsToFit()`, but still respect the content width of a column as a minimum width
3. Allow for data that changes which columns would be narrow or wide
4. Avoid CSS rules to override default responsiveness set by Ag Grid

In solving this problem it would be nice to:

- Get the width of the visible part of the grid after the first render as well as the width of all content - how to do this with Ag Grid and without directly looking at the dom?
- Get the max-content width of a column after first-render (without using autoSizeColumns first)

Note - It does not appear that we can combine `setColumnsToFit()` `autoSizeColumns()` and flex to achieve the goals above. The manner in which Ag Grid has implemented these features conflicts with eachother. Perhaps I am wrong somehow?